# Нужны ли программисту скилы по Github?

Tags: github, непрерывная-интеграция

Планирую работать программистом и делаю небольшой проект, чтобы выложить его на github, как показывающий мои умения. Выложить легко, но там еще есть разные возможности, такие как сборки проекта, настройка зависимостей, CI и т.д. Скажите, в реальной работе программиста в энтерпрайзе, нужны эти умения? Стоит ли погрузиться туда, или лучше поднажать изучение языка и смежные технологии?

Comment: Настройка зависимостей (для python - через requirements.txt или pyproject.toml) - это не специфика Github, это необходимость для любого проекта, использующего внешние зависимости.

Comment: @insolor а setup.py это про другое? не то же что requirements.txt или pyproject.toml?

Comment: setup.py примерно про то же, просто я его не использую (или requirements.txt для простых случаев, или poetry + pyproject.toml для сложных).

Comment: @insolor а сборка проекта это специфика githab? я так понимаю для питона под сборкой подразумевается формирование файла по типу project-1.0.tar.gz

Comment: Нет, не специфика github. Под сборкой разное может подразумеваться, и сборка пакета, и например создание exe файла через pyinstaller.

Answer (score 3):

Всякое бывает. Знаю лично человека, которого на первой работе программистом озадачили настройкой CI. Правда не на GitHub, а как-то очень по странному. Очень по странному. Человек почитал неделю доку по совсем непонятному администрированию Linux и ушёл в нормальное место работать. Где уже в рабочем порядке, когда понадобилось, разобрался с CI (тоже не через GitHub).

В моей практике - CI был уже либо настроен (через TeamCity на маке в подсобке или через GitLab (свой сервер или только раннер на своём сервере или отдельном компе в офисе)) или этим занимались специально обученные люди - DevOps. Максимум что приходилось делать - чуть ковырять настроенные уже CI для модификации или правок. Вне работы - поднимал на своём серваке CI через Jenkins.

---

**Вывод** - изучать CI на GitHub - нет смысла. Либо будет не GitHub, либо не будет CI, либо он уже сделан, либо его сделает специально обученный человек. Если делать придётся таки вам - разберётесь на месте.